# Gurobipy vs Pyomo Discrepancy

Tags: pyomo, gurobi

**Summary:** Using Gurobi, Pyomo and gurobipy generate equivalent .lp files but only the Pyomo version solves. How can I trace Pyomo generating the .lp file to work out the difference?

Hi Everyone,

I was hoping I could get a bit of insight. I've been using Pyomo to develop something in work using the Gurobi solver. I'm thinking of switching to the gurobipy package as I need to optimise a MIQCP model with multiple objectives.

Before I attempted to write the multi-object model in gurobipy I attempted to replicate the model I have in Pyomo but I've been failing miserably. The model .lp produced by Pyomo looks identical to the gurobipy model but the gurobipy model fails whereas the Pyomo version works as intended.

I've looked at the two .lp files generated by both approaches and they seem similar. To help me diagnose the problem I've tried to follow the workflow of Pyomo in generating the .lp file but I'm not having much success.

Happy to share any data/information to help diagnose the problem.

Appreciate any help, I'm starting to go insane haha.

Thanks,
Fraser :)

Comment: More information is needed. Please post the last ~20 lines of the logs from both cases.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.